# Do something if .contains("something") option is not present in select menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out a way to set `myVariable = false` if `.contains("exampleValue")` look up for an option does not find it.

This is what I tried

```
try {                
   $('select').find('option:contains("exampleValue")').prop('selected', true);
} catch(e) {
   console.log(e);
   myVariable = false;
}
```

But `catch` never executes.

Comment: jQuery's find returns an empty collection if nothing was found, it does not throw an exception.

Comment: ....are you expecting the line to throw an exception? Because that's what `try catch` catches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `catch` doesnt execute because nothing in the `try` throws an error- instead of a `try/catch` you can do:

```
var option = $('select').find('option:contains("exampleValue")');
if (option.length) {
    option.prop("selected", true);
} else {
    myVariable = false;
}
```